# Modifying a commit of a branch from the corresponding commit from another branch

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging, git-checkout

I had a git repo that looked something like this:

```
c1->c2->c3->c4 (mainline)
              \
               \ c6->c7->c8 (other branch)
```

I created a new branch called `my branch` from `c4` on mainline, and added a commit `c5` to `my branch`. Now my git repo looks something like this.

```
               c5 (my branch)
               /
c1->c2->c3->c4/ (mainline)
              \
               \ c6->c7->c8 (other branch)
```

The `c4` of `mainline` was in code review and I had to modify the `c4` of `mainline` after I got suggestions. However the changes do not appear in the `c4` of `my branch`. Is there any way I can get all `c4` changes from `mainline` to the `c4` of `my branch`?

Edit: Eventually I will have to merge `my branch` to `mainline` and push `c5` for review as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modified your commit `c4` on the `mainline` branch, you created a new commit hash.

A way to fix it would be to restart from `c4` and apply the changes of `my branch`:

```
git checkout mainline
git checkout <hash-of-c4>      # go to updated c4
git checkout -b my-branch-new  # create branch
git cherry-pick <hash-of-c5>   # apply c5
```

`my-branch-new` should have both the changes of `c4` and of `c5`

---

Answer (score 0):

I take it you mean `c5` of `my branch`.

You should just be able to run `git rebase -i mainbranch` while on `my branch`, then commit the result, to get all of the later commits of `mainline`. That will put `c5` ahead of any changes that you made on `mainbranch`.

Secondly, you could just run `git merge mainline` from `my branch`, but that would make a new merge commit which isn't always desireable.

A third option would be to just cherry-pick any commits with the hash from `mainbranch` into `my branch`.

See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: There has not been any additional commits on `mainbranch`. Its `c4` has been amended. Will rebase still work?

Comment: Ah i see, I misunderstood. Yes see the above comment. In that case `cherry-pick` is the right approach, see the above answer from shamba